# Show Apple Alert Badge In APP Without APNS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, alerts

I have a main menu in my monotouch app that has 4 icons which go to various other screens.  I would like to put an alert badge on one of the icons when my alert criteria has been met.  Is there a way to do this using applicationIconBadgeNumber or something similar?

Comment: What do you mean icons? You mean the app icon? or a UITabBar?

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific - I'd like it to appear on a UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a `UITabBarController` than this code will do what you need

```
viewController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = 1;
```

Where the `viewcontroller` is the UIViewController which is associated with the tab]

If you would like to add it to a `UIButton` you can use this class [here](http://www.spaulus.com/2010/09/create-a-custom-iphone-ipad-badge/?lang=en)

That should allow you do it.

Comment: Thanks but I would actually like the badge to appear on a UIButton inside my app if thats possible?

Comment: OK, See my edit for a link for a custom class that will allow you to do it.

Comment: thank you for that, will those classes work within monotouch? they appear to be straight xcode.  I should also add that I'm using the setbackgroundimage property of the UIButtons.

Comment: Don't think so. Not sure how monotouch works. You may have to translate the code to C# yourself. It would be unlikely to find a similar library for this. Your other option would be to create your own class and use an image for the badge, and a standard label for the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add badges to arbitrary buttons or views. You could manage it yourself. You could create the badge as an image and draw it outside your buttons bounds, at the location you want it to appear. You'll want to make sure clipToBounds is set to `NO` so it shows.